# Facing issue while running jmeter with docker - it says that jmeter command not found when using with --mount or -v command

Tags: docker, jmeter

I am using **justb4/jmeter** image for running jmeter with docker

ref for this image is here [https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter][1]

sample test runs well when we give command like
**docker run jmeter -n -t bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl** [Tagged image name as jmeter]

but then I am trying with these

**docker run --mount type=bind,source="E:/xxxxxx/dockerContent",target="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin" jmeter -n -t bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl**

**docker run -v E/xxxxxxxx/dockerContent:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin jmeter -n -t bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl**

it shows following error

*

```
START Running Jmeter on Sun Jun 6 12:46:08 CEST 2021
JVM_ARGS=-Xmn2138m -Xms8552m -Xmx8552m
jmeter args=-n -t bin/example.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl
/entrypoint.sh: line 29: jmeter: command not found*
```

Ref for entrypoint.sh is [https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/entrypoint.sh][1]

Why it's happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you run next command you could see `jmeter` binary is under the folder of `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin`:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=busybox justb4/jmeter which jmeter
/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter
```

But, when you define bind mount as next:

```
-v E/xxxxxxxx/dockerContent:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin
```

You use the folder on host machine to override the folder `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin` in container, then when container run, it certainly can't find the `jmeter` binary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I didn't get that. what is the wrong in it if I tried to mount /opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin this folder. I can run same file using this command - docker run jmeter -n -t bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl.

Comment: If I am running this command  docker run -v E/sameer/dockerContent:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/examples jmeter -n -t bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx -l bin/example-run1.jtl - it gives me following error The file /opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx doesn't exist or can't be opened

Comment: In container, `jmeter` is located in `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin`. `-v E:/sameer/dockerContent:/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin` means, you will use the folder on host (E:/sameer/dockerContent) to override the folder in container (/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin), so the binary `jmeter` nolonger in `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/`, it's be flushed by your mount.

Comment: For you second comments, enter into the container to see if `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx` really exist or not, need to narrow down the root cause. Above answer is just to tell you why `jmeter: command not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the entrypoint.sh file from git repo https://github.com/justb4/docker-jmeter/blob/master/entrypoint.sh and add it to bin directory of jmeter on your local system. This will resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).